# Do we have $|\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q} | = |\mathbb{Q}|?$ or $|]a,b[|= |\mathbb{R}|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm stuck into two proof about cardinality and countable set :

I have to prove that |$\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$| = |$\mathbb{Q}$|, i have a hint in my lessons which is $|\mathbb{N}|= |\mathbb{Q}|$, but I don't know how to proceed.
This is what I did for the moment :
Since  $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, it exist a $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$ which is a bijection. I define g: $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $$g(m,n)=2^m(2n+1)-1$$ which is bijective.
then $g \circ (f \times f)$ is a bijection  $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$

Another question is to prove that $|]a,b[|= |\mathbb{R}|$, for $a<b.$ I have a hint which is to find a monotone continuous function $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: [MathJax in titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831). Be sure to include at least some plain words.

Comment: For the second question, note that tan is a bijection from (-pi/2, pi/2) to R and there is a linear bijection between  (-pi/2, pi/2)  and (a,b) for a < b.

Comment: I am tempted between closing this as a duplicate, or as "too broad".

Comment: What do you wanted close this question @AsafKaragila? Some answe to this are rather clear

Comment: @Guy: Both of these questions were answered other threads. Moreover, the two questions being distinct, this falls under the umbrella of "too broad".

Comment: OK I see thanks

Answer (score 3):

So you have proved that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb N$. And you know that there is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$. Therefore, there is a bijection, between $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb Q$. So, they have the same cardinal.

Comment: What about thé last question ?

Comment: @GuyFsone See the comment by William Ellot to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

the first question is easier since we have 
$$ f^{-1}\circ g \circ (f \times f):
\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}\to \Bbb Q$$

is a bijection. 
the first arrow map is what you proved and the second was your hint.

For  the last question it suffices to prove for $a=-1 $ and $b=1$. Consider
$$x\mapsto \frac{1}{e^{-x}+1}~~~or ~~~~ x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|+1}~~~~~or~~~ x\mapsto \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan x.$$
which  are bijections from $\Bbb R$ to $(-1,1)$.